# How to find prime numbers between two intervals? I made one but this doesn't work

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

C programming beginner here. I have an assignment in which I have to find the prime numbers between two intervals. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  // This is a program to calculate the prime number between two numbers
  printf("Enter two numbers!:");
  int a, b, i, j, num1, num2;
  scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
  if (a < b) {
    for (num1 = (a + 1); num1 < b; num1++) {
      for (i = 2; i < num1; i++) {
        if ((num1 % i) == 0)
          break;
        else
          continue;
      }
      if ((num1 % i) == 0)
        continue;
      else {
        printf("%d between %d and %d is a prime number!\n", num1, a, b);
        continue;
      }
    }
  } else if (b < a) {
    for (num2 = (b + 1); num2 < a; num2++) {
      for (j = 2; j < num2; j++) {
        if ((num2 % j) == 0)
          break;
        else
          continue;
      }
      if ((num2 % j) == 0)
        continue;
      else {
        printf("%d between %d and %d is a prime number!\n", num2, b, a);
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This yields output:

```
Enter two numbers!:20
30
```

What is wrong in this? I have been doing this for many days. I also tried using the goto statement but without any progress. Maybe I have been doing this all wrong. What can be done in this?

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step through the code line by line.

Comment: `if((num1%i)==0)` you'll find that `i` is the same value as `num1` for the prime number case. Which evaluates to true instead of false as intended.

Comment: @kaylum If `20` is assigned to `int a`, then `num1` comes as `21` and `num1%i` becomes `21%2` which is !=0

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the second `if((num1%i)==0)`. The one outside the inner `for` loop. Just run it in a debugger and/or even basic debug print statements will show you that.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @kaylum. I got the required output. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number is divisible by itself (without a remainder). So, when your inner `for` loops (such as `for (i = 2; i < num1; i++) {...`) reach their conclusion **without** a break-out, then the loop index (`i` in this case) will be equal to `num1` ... because that's when you told the loop to stop. Thus, in the following `if ((num1 % i) == 0)`, `num1` and `i` will be the same, giving a zero remainder and skipping the display of the found prime number.

To fix this, just test that `i` and `num1` aren't the same, first (and similarly for `j` and `num2` in the second part of the code).

Furthermore, your two `else ... continue` 'blocks' in those two *inner* loops are entirely redundant, as there is nothing else in the loops' bodies to 'skip'.

Try this:

```c
int main()
{
    //This is a program to calculate the prime number between two numbers
    printf("Enter two numbers!:");
    int a, b, i, j, num1, num2;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    if (a < b) {
        for (num1 = (a + 1); num1 < b; num1++) {
            for (i = 2; i < num1; i++) {
                if ((num1 % i) == 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (i != num1 && (num1 % i) == 0) // If i == num1, then we've found a prime number!
                continue;
            else {
                printf("%d between %d and %d is a prime number!\n", num1, a, b);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (b < a) {
        for (num2 = (b + 1); num2 < a; num2++) {
            for (j = 2; j < num2; j++) {
                if ((num2 % j) == 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (j != num2 && (num2 % j) == 0)
                continue;
            else {
                printf("%d between %d and %d is a prime number!\n", num2, b, a);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.